# Cleaning for SQL user vars in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a Symfony2 function to clean user inputs?

This is my code so far;

```
    $action_id = $this->getRequest( )->query->get('actionid');

    $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
    $query   = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM api_codes WHERE `action_id` = "' . $action_id . '" LIMIT 1');
```

Is getting the action_id from a form, so user input. I wonder if there is a method on symfony2 to clean that var besides the clasic php functions for cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Symfony provides any specific helper/method at the controler level to clean user inputs. However, [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) comes with [sanitization](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#dynamic-parameters-and-prepared-statements) for database (SQL) injections.

Put another way, from the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#dynamic-parameters-and-prepared-statements),

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM api_codes WHERE `action_id` = :action_id LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindValue("action_id", $action_id); // Which would prevent SQL Injection
$stmt->fetchAll(); // Which could also be done in a one line refactoring
```

Answer (score 1):

You should at least use parameters with DBAL ( since that's what you are using ):

```
$conn->fetchAll(
  'SELECT * FROM api_codes WHERE `action_id` = :id LIMIT 1',
   array("id"=>$action_id)
);
```

or your code is opened to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about SQL escaping you can use `$conn->quote($input);` in your current example. You can also use prepared statements like Ahmed suggested.